# Turn off animation Jquery Accordion

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-animate, accordion

How can i turn off the animation effect on this accordion? so that when I click the sections it just opens instantly, rather than slow drop down?

www.immateriallabour.com/EBH-Pub

```
      <script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true
});
({ animate: false });
});
</script>
```

Comment: To open accordions instantly is sign of a poor UI which leads to a poor UX

Comment: I agree, but the person I'm building the site for insists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to prevent the accordion animation, you should pass the appropriate property as part of the configuration object, as follows:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#accordion").accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         animate: false
     });
 });
```