# Anchor jump link doesn't work when the tabs is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery accordion tabs and a few anchors link throughout the content. I was wondering if the ancor link is clicked and then the tab opens up and the page scrolls down to it. 
The jump link is working when the tab is opened but it's not working when the tab is closed.
Could you tell me how to make it work? Thank you

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="#jump-here-1">Jump Here 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#jump-here-2">Jump Here 2</a></li>
</ol>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="testing">Tab 1</h3>
    <div>
        <h4><a id="jump-here-1">Jump Here 1</a></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce magna augue, pretium quis commodo vel,
            tristique quis odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia
            Curae; Phasellus sollicitudin neque id odio dignissim ac dignissim libero iaculis. Sed lectus odio,
            vehicula et placerat ut, posuere sit amet dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="testing">Tab 2</h3>
    <div>
        <h4><a id="jump-here-2">Jump Here 2</a></h4>
        <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris et nisl orci, eget faucibus neque. Suspendisse bibendum nisi ut
            ligula imperdiet non dignissim lectus congue. Proin id nisi arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
            torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            if(!$.isEmptyObject(ui.newHeader.offset())) {
                $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: ui.newHeader.offset().top }, 'slow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have the demo here https://jsfiddle.net/q6mg40Lj/

Comment: So, what you want is that if I click on 'jump1' It scrolls to the bottom of 'Tab 1' when this last is closed?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want

Comment: you can see my answer and let me know if it worked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the accordion api to open the relevant accordion when it is clicked:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", index);
```

You will need to know in advance which accordion "tab" your button resides within and this quite badly conflicts with your existing scroll-to code.

Updated relevant parts of your code:

```
<li><a href="#jump-here-1" data-accordion='0'>Jump Here 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#jump-here-2" data-accordion='1'>Jump Here 2</a></li>
```

and

```
$("a[data-accordion]").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("accordion");
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", id);
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q6mg40Lj/1/

You can use similar/alternative methods to determine which accordion your target anchor resides within by parsing the href, finding the target, finding the closest(parent) tab and then finding that tab's sibling index.

---

**Update**: If the target is at the bottom of the tab, it can't be jumped-to by the browser as it's not yet visible.

The jquery accordion api provides another solution for this:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

In your code this can be implemented as:

```
var target = $(this).attr("href");
$("#accordion").one("accordionactivate", function( event, ui ) {
  $(document).scrollTop($(target).offset().top);
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q6mg40Lj/4/

You could possibly provide a 'smooth scroll' rather than the jump, but that's just semantics on setting the scroll position.

Comment: Thank you Freedomn-m, it opens the tab but when I put the anchor in the bottom then the page won't scroll to it.

Comment: Probably because your other scroll code is forcing it back to the top

Comment: Nope, because the built-in accordion code is forcing it to the top: https://jsfiddle.net/q6mg40Lj/2/

Comment: Ok, more likely it's because the anchor-target still isn't visible so there's nothing to jump to - it's not that it's forcing it to the top, it's that it's still expanding the tab. You could disable the animation and it works, but it's bad UX  https://jsfiddle.net/q6mg40Lj/3/ see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708549/turn-off-animation-jquery-accordion

Comment: You could add a `setTimeout`, but seems like a sloppy solution

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, this is exactly what I want, thank you so much. You're right the scroll animation is forcing it back to top, but that's ok I don't need the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event in your `document.ready` and it will work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#openTab1').click(function() {
    $('.testing').eq(0).click();
    
    setTimeout(function(){ $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#openTab1").offset().top}, 'slow'); }, 200);
    
  });
  $('#openTab2').click(function() {
    $('.testing').eq(1).click();
    
    setTimeout(function(){ $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#openTab2").offset().top}, 'slow'); }, 200);
    
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    activate: function(event, ui) {
      if (!$.isEmptyObject(ui.newHeader.offset())) {
        $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({
          scrollTop: ui.newHeader.offset().top
        }, 'slow');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Verdana", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 80%;
}

p.test {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Verdana", "sans-serif";
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#accordion {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ol>
  <li><a id="openTab1">Jump Here 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="openTab2">Jump Here 2</a></li>
</ol>

<p>More text here... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce magna augue, pretium quis commodo vel, tristique quis odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae</p>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="testing">Tab 1</h3>
  <div>
    <h4><a id="jump-here-1">Jump Here 1</a></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce magna augue, pretium quis commodo vel, tristique quis odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus sollicitudin neque id odio
      dignissim ac dignissim libero iaculis. Sed lectus odio, vehicula et placerat ut, posuere sit amet dolor.</p>

  </div>
  <h3 class="testing">Tab 2</h3>
  <div>
    <h4><a id="jump-here-2">Jump Here 2</a></h4>
    <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris et nisl orci, eget faucibus neque. Suspendisse bibendum nisi ut ligula imperdiet non dignissim lectus congue. Proin id nisi arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos.</p>
  </div>

</div>

<p class="test">More text here... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce magna augue, pretium quis commodo vel, tristique quis odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim and Freedomn-m,  the code is working to open the tab but the page won't scroll to anchor, I've tried to put the anchor in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kug487wL/)

```
$('li a').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  $('#accordion h3').eq(index).click();
})
```

Comment: Thank you Ewwink, the code is working to open the tab, but the page won't scroll to anchor when the anchor is in the bottom.

Comment: it working if I put the link in the bottom, see https://jsfiddle.net/qeg3ms09/ can you show your fiddle

Comment: @ewwink I think OP means the target-anchor, not the click-able-link  https://jsfiddle.net/qeg3ms09/